# Echo the key from a select-box in Array with get_option (Settings API)

Tags: array, options

I'm trying to print a key from one select box. I'm using the WordPress Settings API. This is the array:

```
$options = array (
array(  "name" => "Styles & Fonts",
        "type" => "title"),
            array(  "type" => "open"),
            array(  "name" => "Color scheme",
                    "desc" => "Select the color scheme for the theme.",
                    "type" => "select",
                    "id" => "st_styles",
                    "options" => array("style", "dark", "grey", "green", "red"),
                    "std" => "style"),
            array(  "name" => "Loop style",
                    "desc" => "Select the style loop for the theme.",
                    "type" => "select",
                    "id" => "st_loops",
                    "options" => array('default' => 'Normal (default)', 'small' => 'No thumbnails', 'large' => 'Big thumbnails'),
                    "std" => "style"),
            array(  "type" => "close"),
);
```

You can see 2 examples on this code, the first has the options in an array, and the second has the options in an **associative array**.

I can get the value with this code:

```
echo get_option('st_styles', 'style')
```

If the selected option is 'dark', it prints 'dark'. By default it's 'style'. This works fine!!

But in the second example I used an associative array because I want to show 'Normal (default)' in the select box; then I want to use 'default' (without spaces) as a CSS class. I tried:

```
echo get_option('st_loops', 'default')[key];
//It returns me the letter 'N'; the first of 'Normal (default)', I think.

print array_keys(get_option('st_loops', 'default'));
//Nothing.

echo get_option(array_keys('st_loops', 'default'));
//Nothing.
```

And finally I tried with this:

```
global $options;foreach ($options as $value) {
    if (get_option( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; } else { $$value['id'] = get_option( $value['id'] ); }
    }

    echo $st_loops;
        //Prints 'Normal (default)'.
    echo $st_loops[key];
        //Prints 'N'.
    echo $st_loops[$key];
        //Prints 'N' again.
    print array_keys($st_loops);
        //Prints nothing.
    echo key($st_loops);
        //Prints nothing.
```

So I have no idea what to do about this. I'm sure it's easy but I'm being unlucky.

**Updated 1:** This:

```
global $options;foreach ($options as $value) { 
if (get_option( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; } else { $$value['id'] = get_option( $value['id'] ); }
}
print_r($options);
```

returns this:

```
[29] => Array
    (
        [name] => Loop style
        [desc] => Select the style loop for the theme.
        [type] => select
        [id] => st_loops
        [options] => Array
            (
                [default] => Normal (default)
                [small] => No thumbnails
                [large] => Big thumbnails
            )

        [std] => style
    )
```

**Updated 3:** At the moment, this is the code as provisional solution:

```
$loop_class = get_option('st_loops');
if($loop_class == "Normal (default)") { $loop_class = "default"; }
elseif($loop_class == "No thumbnails") { $loop_class = "small"; }
elseif($loop_class == "Big thumbnails") { $loop_class = "large"; }
echo $loop_class;
```

Easiest way, but too many lines, I think.

Comment: This is really just PHP. `var_dump(get_option('st_loops', 'default'));` should tell you all you need to know, and if something is wrong it should help you spot the problem.

Comment: Thank you. It returns this: string(16) "Normal (default)". Is 'string(16)' a reference to use somewhere? :)

Comment: Post all of the relevant code please.

Comment: This was the full value returned. Anyway I did a print_r() and I updated the post with the information :)

Comment: That is the value, yes, but I am asking for the _code_-- something I van copy an paste into a dev stack and test.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Well, the full code is very big but you can download it from http://blog.themeforest.net/wordpress/create-an-options-page-for-your-wordpress-theme/. There is a link for download. It can be installed as a Wp theme. Then you only need to add one array with a select type and with an associative array 'options' in the functions.php file (like my example), and finally you can do the test, for example, in the header.php file. Finally, here is how I'm retrieving the options: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-theme-options-on-multisite-not-working#post-2204522